# How to add HTML <A> Link in PDF With ASPPDF (Persists.pdf) in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic, persist

I generated the pdf file in classic asp by persists.pdf dll. But I am unable to add html link in this pdf file. I didn't get any example. Can anyone know about it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify html mode when calling `DrawText()`.

```
Canvas.DrawText "Visit <a href=""http://stackoverflow.com"">stack overflow</a>", "x=10, y=10, html=true", Font
```

Reference: http://www.asppdf.com/manual_06.html#6_4